# Como pegar o HTML de outra pagina

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer uma extensão para o chorme, que ao encontrar um campo com o elemento html de cpf, ele gera um cpf e adiciona ao campo e estou com o seguinte problema:

Como posso pegar o html de outras paginas de um dominio por exemplo?

*localhost.meudominio.com.br*

meu `popup.js`

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("idNumber")[0];
  list.getElementsByName("idNumber")[0].innerHTML = "44245498498";
}, false);
```

meu `popup.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CPF Extension</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <script> function randomiza(n) {
  var ranNum = Math.round(Math.random()*n);
  return ranNum;
}

function mod(dividendo,divisor) {
  return Math.round(dividendo - (Math.floor(dividendo/divisor)*divisor));
}

function gerarCPF() {
  var comPontos = false;

  var n = 9;
  var n1 = randomiza(n);
  var n2 = randomiza(n);
  var n3 = randomiza(n);
  var n4 = randomiza(n);
  var n5 = randomiza(n);
  var n6 = randomiza(n);
  var n7 = randomiza(n);
  var n8 = randomiza(n);
  var n9 = randomiza(n);
  var d1 = n9*2+n8*3+n7*4+n6*5+n5*6+n4*7+n3*8+n2*9+n1*10;
  d1 = 11 - ( mod(d1,11) );
  if (d1>=10) d1 = 0;
  var d2 = d1*2+n9*3+n8*4+n7*5+n6*6+n5*7+n4*8+n3*9+n2*10+n1*11;
  d2 = 11 - ( mod(d2,11) );
  if (d2>=10) d2 = 0;
  retorno = '';
  if (comPontos) cpf = ''+n1+n2+n3+'.'+n4+n5+n6+'.'+n7+n8+n9+'-'+d1+d2;
  else cpf = ''+n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6+n7+n8+n9+d1+d2;

  alert(cpf);
}

gerarCPF();
</script>
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Extension</h1>
    <button id="checkPage">...</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer uma requisição `Ajax` para a página, exemplo...

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'dominio.html',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(html) {
        var html= $(html.responseText); 
    }
});
```

O exemplo acima, usa `J-query`, com `javascript` é a mesma lógica porém com mais código.